# Pick unique random numbers in node/express js

Tags: node.js, express

Have to pick unique random numbers from a given array of numbers. We have a list of numbers from that system has to pick unique random numbers.

Should have an option to input count, like if we give 3 system should pick 3 numbers from the given list.

Is there any available library?

Comment: You can try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-item  OR https://www.npmjs.com/package/pick-random

Answer (score 1):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const yourNumbers = [1,2,5,3,4,5,67,34,5345,6623,4234];

let selectedNumbers = [];
let i = 0;
const numbersRequired = 4;
while (i < numbersRequired){
    const pos = crypto.randomBytes(4).readUInt32BE()%yourNumbers.length;
    if (selectedNumbers.includes(yourNumbers[pos])) {
        continue;
    }
    i++;
    selectedNumbers.push(yourNumbers[pos]);
}
console.log(selectedNumbers)
```

I won't describe the code as it's self explanatory. Also handle the scenario where you cannot pick the required amount of numbers when the `yourNumbers` is too short. Also change the byte size if your number list is huge

Answer (score 0):

```
const count = 8
pickedNumbers = [];
randomNumberList = [5,7,22,45,77,33,7,33,11,22,53,46,86,57,88];

for (i =0; i< count ; i++){
  const randArrayIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNumberList.length);
  pickedNumbers.push(randomNumberList[randArrayIndex]);
}

console.log(pickedNumbers);
```

It's a simple calculation. no need for an external library. You can use the random function of the Math object to generate a random number in js. It will return a number between 0 and 1. multiply it with the length of your array list. then it will give you a random index value from the range 0 - your array length. you can use push method of array object to push the numbers you are generating into an empty array. 
control how many times you want this to happen with a loop setting the count value by users' input.